# is the area of a contour comprising the holes that are inside or not?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

As in the question, I computed the contours of each object in an image, using the `findContours()` function and specifing the *RETR_CCOMP* hierarchy.

If I compute the area of a parent contour, using the function `contourArea()`, is opencv considering the whole area comprising all the holes or is it automatically removing the childs contours areas?

I'm asking this in order to be able to remove the area of the holes, after having retrieved the areas of the objects and the holes, if any hole exists.

This is part of the (working) code:

```
[...]
_, contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, 3, True) for cnt in contours0]
for cntIndex in range(0, len(hierarchy[0])):
   #if the current contour has no parent
   if(hierarchy[0, cntIndex][3]==-1):
      #then, it is a parent contour and
      #compute its bounding box
      boundingBox = cv.contourArea(cnt)
[...]
#otherwise, if it has a parent it must be a child
else:
    #which means we found a GAP
    gap = contours[cntIndex]
    boundingBox = cv.contourArea(cnt)
```

[...]

Of course I'm storing the gaps and the objects areas in two variables which, for now, are subtracted in order to get the exact surface covered by the object. Is this the right approach? I think it is, but I need to be 100% sure and I wasn't able to find this piece of information.

Comment: Just wanted to mention this: `contourArea` - with or without gaps - might not give, what you want, see the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1): _Similarly to `moments`, the area is computed using the Green formula. Thus, the returned area and the number of non-zero pixels, if you draw the contour using `drawContours` or `fillPoly`, can be different._

Comment: @HansHirse: well, this is bad news but thank you. I will look into it!

Comment: If you just want to get the areas of each contour, not including holes, then you can either subtract out the child contour areas, OR, just use `connectedComponentsWithStats()` which will give you the area of each connected component, which I think is what you want anyways.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds so I'll go for the subtracting path, which I prefer since I need to store other information as well. Can I be sure that `countourArea()` is returning the whole area without children, even if a child is actually found?

Comment: Yes, because each contour is just a list of points for a single shape; the child contours will show up via the hierarchies but it won't be part of the same contour. You can always draw the contours one by one on blank images to double check :). The only thing I'm unsure of on the hierarchies is what happens if you have nested child components, like a black circle with a white circle in that with a black circle inside that and etc, but that should be easy to figure out with a little playing around. Also it isn't clear what you want in that case, anyways.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out: I was considering each child as a gap, which is not always true, indeed. Ok for the area, now I need to figure out how to deal with this new piece of information since, as you're asking, I only need to figure out first children. Nested children are not to be considered since they already are considered as part of the first-level child. Thank you!